# SQL search problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

So here is my problem: I have a site where I have to search through the stuff on it.
This is my sql sentence:

```
public DataTable Search(string Keyword)
{
    return db.GetData("SELECT * FROM tblBehandlinger WHERE fldYdelse LIKE @1", 
                  "%" + Keyword + "%");
}
```

But as you can see it will only search through the table name "fldYdelse". And I works fine, but my problem is that it wont search through two things.
This I how I want it to be:

```
public DataTable Search(string Keyword)
{
    return db.GetData("SELECT * FROM tblBehandlinger WHERE fldYdelse LIKE 
                       @1 OR fldPris @2", "%" + Keyword + "%");
}
```

This is my backend of the `search.aspx` site:

```
string keyword = Request.QueryString["search"].ToString();

foreach (DataRow item in s.Search(keyword).Rows)
{
    //BLAH BLAH BLAH
}
```

But I can't list it out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the `LIKE` predicate with the second parameter `fldPris` as well. Your sql statement should look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblBehandlinger 
WHERE fldYdelse LIKE @1 
   OR fldPris   LIKE @2
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblBehandlinger 
WHERE fldYdelse LIKE @1 
   OR fldPris @2
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating a parameter (string) in C# is cheap... did you want to use a single parameter twice?

```
return db.GetData("SELECT * FROM tblBehandlinger " +
                  "WHERE fldYdelse LIKE @1 OR fldPris LIKE @2",
                  "%" + Keyword + "%", "%" + Keyword + "%");
```

Or did you really miss the 2nd LIKE?

Comment: Huh.. didnt think of that. But thank you very much! It worked :)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I think you need to wait 15 minutes before accepting the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
return db.GetData("SELECT * FROM tblBehandlinger WHERE fldYdelse LIKE 
                   @1 OR fldPris LIKE @1", "%" + Keyword + "%");
```

It's the same keyword